# Hiding Certificate name from developers

Tags: t-sql

I managed to create a certificate.
And this is how I, as an sa, using it.

```
    create certificate CertLogin
--      authorization app_usr
        from file = 'C:\Project\Login.cer'
        with private key 
        (
            file = 'C:\Project\Login.pvk', 
            decryption by password = 'PVK_File_Password'
        )
```

You notice that I commented out the "authorization app_usr".
app_usr is the userid for running the application.

If I uncomment it, app_usr will be able to see the sys.certificates table,
and do EncryptByCert() & DecryptByCert() manually by themselves using MSSQL.

I am actually wrapping the EncryptByCert() & DecryptByCert()
with encrypted stored procedures, in the hope that I can prevent developers 
to see the password column value in plain text.

If I comment it, the application will not be able to work with the encrypted password column.

My goal is, developers must not be able to hack the values of the password column in the user table by hiding the certificate name. Can you please help me to find out how I can accoplish tis please?

Thanks so much.

Comment: Some thoughts/questions here - 1) are you storing user passwords in the database in a form where they can be retrieved (even if they are encrypted)? If you are, DON'T - store them as a salted one way hash. 2) You need to trust someone - if you can't trust your developers then you have a big problem. 3) Database security (I'm guessing SQL server from the tsql tag) is usually best handled at the database itself using user groups.

Comment: I am doing migration, which has passwords in plain texts in table columns. My method here is already making them encrypted by EncryptByCert(). But now, armed with "app_usr", developers can see the certificate and thus able to run DecryptByCert(). 1) What is "salted one way hash" ? 2) Yes, I have that big problem, boss directive. 3) MS-SQL 2008 R2. User Groups, you mean Roles? How would that be please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, my workaround is found in this blog, [EXECUTE AS someone else – impersonation in stored procedures](http://www.bp-msbi.com/2008/11/recently-i-had-to-implement-stored/).

With this, I am able to put EncryptByCert() & DecryptByCert() in wrappers, and avoid the 'app_usr' to be able to see the certificate name in the sys.certificates table. Thus render the developers unable to decrypt the encrypted password column into plain text manually.

Hope my experience can be useful to others too. Thank you for spending time on this.